# Is there a one line - condition check and code execution operator?

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

Were interested in knowing if it is possible to check a condition and if it's successful, than execute a code - in one line, similar to conditional operator.
Conditional operator looks something like this:

```
condition ? first_expression : second_expression;
```

And what I'm asking is if there is something like this:

```
condition ? code_execution;
```

For example:

```
var i = 0, j = 1;
j==1 ? i = 10;
```

The only way to make this possible is creating some sort of a function which executes desired code and returns some inessential value that later get's assigned to inessential variable. That is something like this:

```
var i = 0, j = 1;
int? tmp = true ? workaround(ref i) : null;

// defined somewhere 
public void workaround(ref int foo){
  foo = 10;
  return null;
}
```

Is there such a thing, or am I just not seeing how something like that should be done?

Comment: What you've described is an `if` statement. That's what it's there for. I would suggest you don't focus on doing things in a single line.

Comment: As a general rule, clarity > terseness. I think every developer goes down the rabbit hole of using ternary expressions for everything when they discover them, but you'll kick yourself when you're trying to understand your code a year down the line.

Comment: Glad to see @JonSkeet ^_^

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer is No.

And IMHO, you should avoid it, it's better to make control flow statements obvious so it is easier to read..

so
`if(j==1) i = 10;` would do

and I personally prefer

```
if(j==1)
{
   i = 10;
}
```

because it's easier to read for me

Comment: I'd add braces to that... yes, it's then 4 lines rather than 1, but it makes it a lot harder to accidentally add something that you *think* is in the body of the statement but isn't really...

Comment: @JonSkeet ahh makes sense. I'm curious though, would it be the same case for guard clauses? and other cases that you are almost certain that it won't have any other LOC added to it?

Comment: What kind of guard clauses are you thinking of? Pattern matching for C# 7? But yes, I pretty much always use braces. I *sometimes* stack `using` statements without braces, but rarely even that.

Answer (score 7):

```
var i = 0, j = 1;
if( j==1) i = 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have done this with the tools you already have :

```
var j = 1;
var i = j == 1 ? 0 : 10;
```